# MySQL WHERE a la NoSQL style

Tags: mysql, select, nosql, where-clause

Is there a way I could search inside a JSON field in MySQL a la NoSQL?
I mean, if I store, let's say, `"{name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', age:'30'}"` in a `VARCHAR` field, could I select and filter it with something like

```
SELECT my_json_field FROM my_table where my_json_field.name = 'John'
```

Regards

Comment: It's not that easy: one has to actually decode JSON each time it should be searched. Check [this lengthy article](http://tech.livingsocial.com/2008/04/14/mysql-stored-function-parsing-a-json-encoded-string.html): these guys' solution can be used in queries too, but it's not quite... performant, may I say.

Comment: This is not even closer to what I'm looking for. They just threat the field as a normal string. I'll looking for something that'll let MySQL _understand_ JSON.

Comment: While MySQL is able to output in JSON, I think it's a long way far from supporting a JSON type field (like XML type in DB2, for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing. MySQL just won't understand JSON and writing regex matches or anything else is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this:

```
 SELECT my_json_field FROM my_table where my_json_field LIKE '% name:\'John\' %'
```

Or more general, depending on the structure of your `my_json_field`:

```
 SELECT my_json_field FROM my_table where my_json_field LIKE '% name: \'John\' %'
```

Comment: You have to include the quotes in the string, too: `LIKE '%name: \'John\'%'`

Comment: Obviously this was an example. I don't know what kind of JSON object will be stored in the field or how many levels it will have. +there could be a "```WHERE name = 'John' AND age > 40```"

Comment: You can build the argument of LIKE as you wish on the application side. Something like : "'%" + field_name +":'"+value+"'%'".

For non-regex predicates, this doesn work, indeed. age > 40 wouldn't work. For such a condition the only thing you can do is to use string functions to extract the field value and compare it to your filtering value.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing such a feature with the `like` operator may kill performance. I advise to use MySQL [fulltext](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) search for this purpose instead of the `like`.

```
create table my_table (my_json_field text);

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD FULLTEXT(my_json_field);

insert into my_table (my_json_field) values ("{name: 'John', surname: 'Doe', age:'30'}");

insert into my_table (my_json_field) values ("{name: 'Pope', surname: 'Benedict', age:'666'}");

select *
from my_table
where MATCH(my_json_field) AGAINST ("Pope" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
'{name: ''Pope'', surname: ''Benedict'', age:''666''}'

select * 
from my_table
where MATCH(my_json_field) AGAINST ("John" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
'{name: ''John'', surname: ''Doe'', age:''30''}'
```

You may notice that I did not add the 'name' filedname to the query, because it is a [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) (that is ignored in the search term).

Also, you'll have to find a way to handle special characters if you want to search for a "fieldname: 'value'" pair.